# CSS img to fill the broswer window WITHOUT keeping aspect ratio

Tags: css, svg

I've been searching for hours on the net, here and elsewhere, for a simple code that allows me to put an img(in this case im using SVG) to stretch and skew accordingly to the browser window size... however everyone has been talking about codes that maintain the aspect ratio... I do not want to maintain the ratio, i just want to force stretch the img/svg onto the 4 edges of the browser... anyone has a simple code for that?

I have been using

```
width:100%;
position: fixed; 
left: 0px; 
top: 0px; 
z-index: 7;
background-size:100% 100%;
```

but to no avail..

Comment: Post your HTML. We don't know if you have a path to the SVG file or the SVG itself.

Comment: Have you tried just adding `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to your root <svg> element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML, there is actually a lot more flexibility with background images then actual images.

The approach I use is to create a `div` element and set it's `background-image` to the image you want to display.

Something link this:

```
#imageDiv
{
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-image:url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/dd3f93d8f93c5908d58711ff9092ba02?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    z-index:1;
}
```

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2t17onko/2/

Comment: so applying this property on `img` tag `max-width` and `max-height` `100%` won't work?

Comment: @KheemaPaney - No. Have you tried setting `min-width` and `min-height` to `100%`? (It probably won't work, but worth a try :-))

Comment: Thanks Andrew I'll try your suggestions.

Comment: thanks, this worked like a charm... originally i tried something like this but it was because I was using svg so it didnt work... now with a png it worked. Thanks again u saved my day